# Is `foo as? Foo` a complete equivalent of `foo as Foo?` in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is `foo as? Foo` a complete equivalent of `foo as Foo?` ?

If yes then why have both?

If no then what's the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`as?` is the [safe cast operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator).

Usually, if you try to cast a variable, and it fails, you get a `ClassCastException`. Using this operator, it just returns `null` instead in this case.

This means that the return type of the `foo as? Foo` expression is actually `Foo?`, because it might return `null`.

---

`foo as Foo?` is a cast of `foo` to the nullable `Foo?` type, this can still produce an exception if the variable isn't of that type (i.e. it's not a `Foo` instance or `null`).